# How to use bitmap from resources instead of the file (migradoc)?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, pdfsharp, migradoc

How to use e.g. bitmap from resources instead of physical image file in class `MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Cell`

in method  `public Image AddImage(string fileName);`
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've added an image with the name "myImage" to your projects resources use this code:

```
Properties.Resources.myImage
```

In your example adjust the parameter:

```
public Image AddImage(Image img);
```

And call it like this:

```
AddImage(Properties.Resources.myImage);
```

If it is required to pass a filename just write the Image to a file first (perhaps to the temp directory):

```
    string fileName = "C:\\image.jpg";

    ((Bitmap)Properties.Resources.myImage).Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    AddImage(fileName);
```